# Determine "p" such that there's only 1 intersection

Tags: linear-algebra

I have four planes with the equations:

$ \ a_1: x +py + pz=p $

$ \ a_2: x + p^2y = p^3 $

$ \ a_3: x + p^2y + pz = p $

$ \ a_4: x + py + 2pz = p $

I have to determine $ \ p$ such that the planes have only 1 intersection point. I'm not so sure how to do this though.

If they were lines with formulas, $ \ y=ax+b $, instead of planes I think the problem would be easier, since you could just substitute in $ \ y $ in one of the equations and then get a quadratic equation. But since these are planes, this is not the case.

Any ideas/hints on how to solve this?

**Edit**

The augmented matrix for this system of equations would look like this:

\begin{bmatrix}
 1&  &p  &p  &p \\ 
 1&  &p^2  &0  &p^3 \\ 
 1&  &p^2  &p  &p \\ 
 1&  &p  &2p  &p 
\end{bmatrix}

My intial thought was to use Gaussian-elimination on it, but I didn't really see how that would help me. Another thought was to find the determinant, but that doesn't really do anything either?

**Edit 2**

After doing Gaussian-elimination I reached this point

\begin{bmatrix}
 1&  p&  p&  p& \\ 
 0&  p^2-p&  0&  0& \\ 
 0&  0&  p&  0& \\ 
 0&  0&  0&  p^3-p& 
\end{bmatrix}

If the system of equations has to have a unique solution, then that means that both $ \ p^2-p$ and $ \ p$ are $ \ 0$, meanwhile $ \ p^3-p$ is not $ \ 0$. However, there doesn't seem to be a solution to this, have I done something wrong?

Comment: You are in a linear algebra class? Write down an augmented matrix.

Comment: Of course do Gaussian elimination. What do you need to know about the rank of the matrix and the rank of the augmented matrix to know there's a unique solution?

Comment: Ahh, I see. When the rank of the matrix is the same as the rank of the augmented matrix, then there is only 1 solution the system of linear equations. Thank you I will try it now.

Comment: Well, you need the rank of both to be $3$ in order to get a unique solution, right?

Comment: You are right, I forgot to mention that the rank also has to match the number of unknown variables.

Answer (score 1):

With $$x=p-py-pz$$ from the first line we get in the last line $$pz=0$$
Can you proceed?

Comment: So every $\ pz$ is "eliminated" from the equations. So know we have one less variable to think about. Is that how I am supposed to understand this?

Answer (score 1):

Solving $a_1, a_2, a_4$ we get the point of their intersection as $P(-p^2, p+1, 0)$, given it exists. For the required value we must find the value of $p$ such that $P$ also lies in $a_3$ however there is no such value for which the planes $a_1, a_2$ and $a_3$ have a unique point of intersection.

Comment: Soo, is the problem even solvable?

Comment: Well, if “there is no such $p$” doesn’t count as a solution, then I guess not.

Comment: Huh, I see. Kinda weird of my professor to give us such a problem, but if this is the case, then that's how it is.

Comment: It is indeed. Rank nullity theorem agrees.